# Django: implementing websockets to work with my existing MVT-based app (Channels seems to need me to throw out my entire existing code)

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I have an existing Django project in the sports domain with apps that are built on the Model-View-Template structure. Many of the models and views are fairly sophisticated and work well currently. Data from the database (scores etc) is combined with some incoming user inputs through forms (HTTP POST requests) to be displayed on a web page via templates.

However, I now need live data to be displayed to users and be automatically refreshed to all the users continuously, either because one of the users entered something new (in the front-end), or because the scores changed during the game (directly enters the back-end).

I've done some research on Stack Overflow as well as tutorials on Youtube/ rest of the web and it appears that for me to use Django Channels, I'd have to start from scratch and build everything ground-up, which I'd like to avoid. How do I use the websocket protocol for my Django app easily without having to completely rework everything that I've done so far?

Comment: i think you need to prepare and show simple work example what you have and what you want. Because now your question  is too broad to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to start from scratch or anything. You just need to add a module using channels. I am assuming that currently, the data is fetched only when the page is refreshed. What you need to do is write a consumer that is used to send messages directly to the client via websocket. Then in the front you can update the widget with the scores on each message received in the websocket. You can also stream user actions through the websocket to the server which will then be broadcasted by the consumer to needed clients. You may not even need to change anything in the existing code.
It will be easier to understand how this works and how you can incorporate it to your project by reading the channels tutorials. It became clearer to me after reading it so I would advice you do the same

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I realized this after watching a lot more videos and reading stuff written on other blogs. Looks like I need to bring in a lot of my previous code from my view into a new consumer now. There's no way to just convert my view into a consumer to just start broadcasting the channel.

I will close this question now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can't easily convert your view into a user as it is based on request-response while consumers are based on the 2 way communication(assuming you're using the websocket conumers). Especially if you're using the async consumers(which you should be using). However, there is a package that converts DRF views to consumers if you're using DRF. I would advice you implement the consumers separately though, as it will help you understand the lib better. And the consumer can work alongside the views too